# Parse a Json with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying the new iOS language, but I'm getting issue. I will parse a JSON like the following:

```
{
   "coord":{
      "lon":-0.13,
      "lat":51.51
   },
   "sys":{
      "message":0.1947,
      "country":"GB",
      "sunrise":1404964557,
      "sunset":1405023356
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":501,
         "main":"Rain",
         "description":"moderate rain",
         "icon":"10d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"cmc stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":291.87,
      "pressure":1018,
      "humidity":87,
      "temp_min":287.15,
      "temp_max":295.45
   },
   "wind":{
      "speed":3.1,
      "deg":350,
      "var_beg":320,
      "var_end":30
   },
   "rain":{
      "3h":0.5
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":75
   },
   "dt":1404999902,
   "id":2643743,
   "name":"London",
   "cod":200
}
```

I got the JSON from a weather forecast service, until now I made the following method:

```
func getWeatherFinished(json:NSDictionary) {
    if (json != nil) {
        var weather: NSArray = json.objectForKey("weather") as NSArray
        var weatherDict: NSDictionary = weather.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary
        var weatherConditions: NSString = weatherDict.objectForKey("description") as NSString

        var mainDict: NSDictionary = json.objectForKey("main") as NSDictionary
        var temp: NSString = mainDict.objectForKey("temp") as NSString
        var humidity: NSString = mainDict.objectForKey("humidity") as NSString
        var minTemp: NSString = mainDict.objectForKey("temp_min") as NSString
        var maxTemp: NSString = mainDict.objectForKey("temp_max") as NSString

        var windDict: NSDictionary = json.objectForKey("wind") as NSDictionary
        var speed: NSString = windDict.objectForKey("speed") as NSString
        var deg: NSString = windDict.objectForKey("deg") as NSString
    }
}
```

But when I run the app it crash and I don't know why. What's wrong in my code? Why it's crashing?

ERROR SCREENSHOT:
[image]

When I get the JSON I wrote this code:

```
    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {

            var json: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receiveData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(1), error: nil)
        if let jsonDict = json as? NSDictionary {
            getWeatherFinished(json as NSDictionary)
        }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any error details for the crash? Also when the type can be inferred by the assignment you do not need to include it as part of the declaration.

Comment: I put the screenshot of the error, no other information

Comment: You're saying `as NSDictionary` which does not allow for the possibility that JSONObjectWithData is `nil` due to an error. Use `as? NSDictionary` to get an optional `NSDictionary` (`NSDictionary?`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking to make sure your JSON is non-nil and can be a dictionary:

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var json: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receiveData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(1), error: nil)
    if let jsonDict = json as? NSDictionary{
        getWeatherFinished(json)
    }

}
```

This line is crashing because it the object with the key 'temp' is not an NSString.

```
var temp: NSString = mainDict.objectForKey("temp") as NSString
```

From your json it looks like it is a number, so you could try this instead:

```
var tempNum: NSNumber = mainDict.objectForKey("temp") as NSNumber
var temp: NSString = tempNum.stringValue()
```

Comment: Still the same: it crashes in the same way... I updated the code in my question

Comment: Try turning on exception breakpoints and find the line that is crashing: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: I tried and it crashed at the following lines
`var temp: NSString = mainDict.objectForKey("temp") as NSString`
and it crashed here and in the same instructions

Comment: there is no NSString for that key then. You can use an optional to prevent the crash though `var temp = mainDict.objectForKey("temp") as? NSString`

Comment: with the ? it won't crash if there is no NSString in the dictionary for that key. it will set temp to nil instead

Comment: now it works, but we are sure that I can show the value on a label?

Comment: it looks like the problem is temp is an NSNumber and you are trying to use it as a string